# IAsyncEnumerator item becomes null

Tags: azure-service-fabric, nullreferenceexception, service-fabric-stateful, reliable-dictionary

While iterating my ReliableDictionary with an enumerator, the "Current.Value" returns null because the line "totalLength += val.Length;" throws NullPointerException.
How is this possible?

```
public async Task RemoveItemsPeriodically()
{
    try
    {
        var totalLength = 0;
        var dict= await this.stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, Item>>("dict");
        using (ITransaction tx = this.stateManager.CreateTransaction())
        {
            IAsyncEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Item>> asyncEnumerable = await dict.CreateEnumerableAsync(tx);
            List<string> removeKeys= new List<string>();
            using (IAsyncEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, Item>> asyncEnumerator = asyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator())
            {
                while (await asyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken.None))
                {
                    if (asyncEnumerator == null || asyncEnumerator.Current.Value == null)
                    {
                        Log();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var keyValue = asyncEnumerator.Current;
                        var key = keyValue.Key;
                        var val= keyValue.Value;
                        totalLength += val.Length;
                        if (this.checkToDelete(item.DeleteValue))
                        {
                            removeKeys.Add(key);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (string keyToRemove in removeKeys)
                {
                    dict= await this.stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, Item>>("dict");
                    await dict.TryRemoveAsync(tx, keyToRemove);
                }
            }

            await tx.CommitAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `totalLength` defined?

Comment: You can assume somewhere above. I shortened the code for readability

Comment: Why aren't you using `await foreach` ? There's never any reason to work with `IAsyncEnumerator` or `IEnumerator` objects directly.

Comment: Please post the full exception text. Your code already guards against a `null` dictionary value, which is *not* something unusual. The `else` block wouldn't execute if `KeyValuePair.Value` was `null`.